# Using Spring @Scheduled annotation in OSGi

Tags: java, spring, osgi, scheduler

I am following this guide https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/ to set up a scheduled function in my application. However, the guide assumes I have a main method in my application to put the `@SpringBootApplication` and `@EnableScheduling` annotations on. I'm using OSGi and creating bundles and therefore don't have a main method, so is there a way to use the `@Scheduled` annotation?

I have added the `awaitility` dependency to my pom like the guide asks. Here is my class:

```
import org.osgi.service.component.annotations.Component;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeDefinition;
import org.osgi.service.metatype.annotations.AttributeType;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.Scheduled;

@Component
@EnableScheduling
public class SchedulerConfig {
  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SchedulerConfig.class);

  private static final SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");

  @Scheduled(fixedRate = 5000)
  public void reportCurrentTime() {
    log.info("The time is now {}", dateFormat.format(new Date()));
  }
}
```

Getting this error, which I wasn't getting before adding this stuff:

```
Error executing command: Error executing command on bundles:
    Error starting bundle 284: Unable to resolve bundleName.api [284](R 284.13): missing requirement [bundleName.api [284](R 284.13)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.scheduling.annotation) Unresolved requirements: [[bundleName.api [284](R 284.13)] osgi.wiring.package; (osgi.wiring.package=org.springframework.scheduling.annotation)]
```